# Does calling a javascript function multiple time cause any unwanted issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So how does the javascript interpreter handle multiple functions calls that are the same? Does it override the previous, or cause some kind of clutter?

I have written functions in the console, the newest one seems to always work and override the old one, I am always afraid the old functions are stored away, which I assume can cause performance issues/bloat.

So for example.

```
$('body').on('click', function() { alert('hello') });
```

Will alert `hello`, then I rewrite the same function alerting hello again

```
$('body').on('click', function() { alert('hello') });
```

What happens? Does it replace it, create a new copy?

Comment: You are binding the event twice, so your code happens twice per click

Comment: You're binding two events, with two identical, but *distinct* anonymous functions. This is why JSLint advises against defining anonymous functions inside a loop.

Comment: does the first one and than the second one

Comment: Did you try running that code? If you do that then you'll find your answer instantly.

Comment: I really dont understand the - votes but whatever some people have their panties in a bunch and think they are superior. Thanks for all those who helped. So its obvious, avoid this and make sure you cleanup events, hence why it's important in backbone or whatever client side framework to destroy your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the event listener will remain active even if you bind more events to the same element, even if the event is identical to the previously bound event.

You can observe this behaviour in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alaneor/s9s329kw/1/).

```
// Example with anonymous function - this will print 'hello' twice
$('#btn1').on('click', function() { alert('hello') })
$('#btn1').on('click', function() { alert('hello') })

// Example with named function - this will work exactly the same
function sayHello () {
    alert('hello')
}

$('#btn2').on('click', sayHello)
$('#btn2').on('click', sayHello)
```

To remove previously bound listeners, you must use the [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) method or its jQuery alternative, [unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind).

Comment: Thanks to you, and screw the people who down voted :)